# fatal error: ots/libots.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-16.04

I was trying to install OTS.

I did

```
sudo apt-get install libots

sudo -E pip install ots
```

But I get the following error :

[image: The errors]

How could I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `libots-dev` package. I guess it contains the relevant header files. Use `apt-get` again.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Wasted my 4 hours on this today.